# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.* in Page Tab returns 500 error

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am developing an app for Facebook which is stored on my server and included in the iFrame on Facebook. I have the following code to Initialize the Facebook app and check if the user is logged in/authorized.
P.S. APP_ID and APP_SECRET are only displayed in this post. On my server they have the actual values.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;

//Initialize the app
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');

//Check if user is logged in and authorized
$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try{
    $session = $helper->getSession();
    echo "Setting...";
}catch(FacebookRequestException $ex){
    echo "Facebook error";
}catch(\Exception $ex){
    echo "Local issue";
}

//If logged in
if($session){
    echo "Logged in";
}

echo "End...";
?>
```

When I load the page on Facebook, it just shows that the server returned 500 server error in the browser console, and page doesn't display anything at all.

I am using FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php because it's inside the iFrame on Facebook and it's the way I get user's session.
I am running PHP v5.4.23 which should, in theory, support my new code.

What could result in this error? Can it be my host, or is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: We're going to add a login helper for Page Tab apps, but it's not currently supported.

Comment: Is this class going to be added in the near future, or you don't know yet? I have a project due in two weeks, and I am wondering whether I should wait for this feature to be added, or just work with an older SDK?

Comment: If you're in a tight spot, feel free to code up a fix to the new SDK yourself and submit a pull request on github.